# Google_spreadsheet how can i change the Row color

Tags: ruby

I'm rubynewbie. 
My application using google_spreadsheet gem.

I want to change my google spreadsheet row color.
Can anybody show me the sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Ruiz commented looking at the documentation. This is important, you can usually find the answer to your question. I have never used this gem before, but just looking at the documentation I found the following on the spreadsheet guide:

```
 format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :color => :blue,
                                   :weight => :bold,
                                   :size => 18
```

[Spreadsheet documentation](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html). The google-spreadsheet uses the spreadsheet classes and methods.